# Merging few lists into one using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, merge

Is there a simple way to take few lists of the same size and create a new one ouf of their min/max values in each index with linq? I mean how to compare items at same index and pick which one is Max or Min like here:

```
List<List<int>> Some2dList = new List<List<int>>
                 { new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
                   new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 } } ;
List<int> NewList = new List<int>(5);

for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
{
    int CurrentHighest=0;
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        if (Some2dList[j][i] > CurrentHighest)
            CurrentHighest = Some2dList[j][i];
    }
    NewList.Add(CurrentHighest);
}
//Which gives me {5,4,3,4,5}
```

I've simplified those loops to look clearlier. I know I could use Concat and GroupBy, and then select Max out of each, but for simple types and classes without a key value I can't figure it out.

edit: I shoul've been more precise. List in example are assigned manually, but I'm asking about solution, that would be flexible for ANY amount of lists compared. Also, lists are always same sized.

Comment: Are their always the same ammount of entries in each? (i,e `new double[x,5]`)

Comment: Yes, no need to check whether the value is there. All lists have the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little bit abnormal but seems to work. It assumes there is one list though

```
Enumerable.Range(0, Some2dList.FirstOrDefault().Count)
   .Select(columnIndex => 
       Some2dList.Max(row => row[columnIndex]))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: No worries, Like I said, it assumes there is a minimum of 1 list otherwise you'll get a NRE on FirstOrDefault

Comment: +1. This is probably optimal solution for rectangular case. Note that `FirstOrDefault()` is not much better than `First` in this code as it will throw null reference in either case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I would even go as far as to say use `[0]`, but `FirstOrDefault` looks fancier :) (and thanks for edit)

Answer (score 6):

No limit on the size of *List Of Lists* and  lists can be any length.

```
List<List<int>> Some2dList = new List<List<int>>{ 
        new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
        new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 },
        new List<int> { 8, 9 } 
        };
var res = Some2dList.Select(list => list.Select((i, inx) => new { i, inx }))
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .GroupBy(x => x.inx)
            .Select(g => g.Max(y=>y.i))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: +1. Fancy LINQ for non-rectangular option. Note that if performance is important it is probably not the right approach due to creation of many intermediate collections.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov of course. If performance matters, then it is better to write a non-Linq version.

Comment: Works great, +1, but I'll mark Sayse's answer as the right one as it is simpler. Both of you answered in the same moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
List<int> newList = Some2dList[0].Select((x, column) => Math.Max(x, Some2dList[1][column])).ToList();
```

The trick is taking the overload of Select that allows you to have the index of the item you are working with in the lambra expression : this makes possible compare two items in the two different lists placedat the same index. Obviously if it's the min you are looking for, use Math.Min instead of Math.Max.

Just one thing, I take for granted that the two sublists have the same number of elements.

Comment: Thank you. It works great of course for 2 lists, but what if I have more of them?

Comment: +1 I think it is the answer for case of 2 element array. Note that shows that default one letter naming is sometimes very hard to read with "x,y" for variable names - something like "index" or "column" instead of "y" would be nicer.